# Selenium missing or invalid 'entry.level' Error

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a selenium test which should work just fine (hasn't changed and used to work) but I'm getting this strange error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
  (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 1015
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line 849
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click() in c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement.cs:line 337
...
```

What is this "missing or invalid 'entry.level'" error and how do I fix it?

Comment: I also have same issue on Win10, I have latest chrome and chromedriver still the issue persist. Any sugggestions?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I resolved this by updating my chrome driver to the latest version (v2.34 at the time of writing).

You can get the chromedriver here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

just download the .exe file then replace the chromedriver file in your project's selenium/bin folder.

Comment: There is also http://chromedriver.chromium.org/ if you want to download from a more official looking url (why the site isn't https is beyond me)

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users, I made a

```
webdriver-manager clean
```

and then a

```
webdriver-manager update
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you've set the browser exe correctly, like to execute your tests on Chrome you would need chromedriver.exe in your path.

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+
                "\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think, though, that in my case it was fail even with these settings until I updated my chrome driver. This might work for others though.

Answer (score 1):

Please update all your maven dependencies:

- maven-compiler-plugin
- maven-surefire-plugin
- webdrivermanager
- selenium-chrome-driver

Comment: In my case we were using ASP.NET but the concept of updating the driver to solve the issue is the same. Thanks for your answer!